What are the Latest Breakthroughs in Black Hole Firewall Research?
I am delving into the intriguing realm of black hole firewalls, specifically the AMPS (Almheiri-Marolf-Polchinski-Sully) firewall paradox, and am keen to pursue further research in this field. Could you suggest a recent, thorough review article on this topic? Additionally, what are the latest advancements and developments in this area of study?

Asking what the latests advancements is a bad fit for the site's format.  It is essentially a list-type question which has no objectively correct answer.  It also has no end - people can keep answering indefinitely.

Thanks for the comment. I try to ask my questions in a better way from now on.

A short and sweet review of the firewalls would be https://courses.physics.illinois.edu/phys419/sp2021/l25.pdf
A good introduction to the information paradox can be found here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.1038
Recently, the islands resolution to the information paradox has come up which relies on the AdS/CFT correspondence. Relevant papers are:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.08255
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.11977
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.06872

There is also the long standing fuzzball resolution to the information paradox. The relevant papers for that are:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0502050
https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0701216

And lastly, I would like to mention a recent paper that contrasts the two paradigms of fuzzballs and islands that would bring you up to speed to the unsolved issues in the field:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.05295
Hope this helps!

Please do not link directly to documents.  We prefer links to abstract pages where possible.

Thank you so much. I will read them. However, I am looking for a technical paper on firewalls. I searched a lot but did not find any mathematical model/calculation for the firewall hypothesis.

I think the chapter Firewalls in the book by Robert Mann is good. I am not sure if there are other more detailed explanations. The book can be found here: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-14496-2. I also found this paper by t'Hooft which might be interesting to you: https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.16890
